# How to install IRSTLM (automake warning during the build)?

Tags: compiling, make, configure, autoconf

I am trying to install MT.

So this purpose, i am trying to install "irstlm-5.80.03" version on "Ubuntu 14.04," but, when I give the command `./regenerate-makefiles.sh` then found following error:

```
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Calling /usr/bin/autoconf...
Calling /usr/bin/automake --add-missing...
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in:9: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.
For more info, see:
configure.in:9: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
configure.in:19: installing './compile'
configure.in:19: installing './config.guess'
configure.in:19: installing './config.sub'
configure.in:9: installing './install-sh'
configure.in:9: installing './missing'
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
src/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
```

​So kindly tell me, how can I resolve this issues in the same OS. For this purpose, I have installed to "gcc-4.6, g++-4.6 and libboost (1.54 version)".

Comment: What issue do you want to resolve? Everything seems fine, no errors are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a *warning*, no *error*. The reason is that autoconf deprecated the use of `configure.in` and in 2012, there was the proposal to drop it alltogether ([see here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf-patches/2012-05/msg00004.html)).

There are no errors in the code you posted, so your software either compiled correctly or failed elsewhere.

Comment: First of thanks your answer. But when I give other command like :                                                             make and make install then get these error: make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/atul-thinkcentre/tool/irstlm-5.80.03/scripts'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/atul-thinkcentre/tool/irstlm-5.80.03'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/atul-thinkcentre/tool/irstlm-5.80.03'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/atul-thinkcentre/tool/irstlm-5.80.03'

Comment: _Nothing to be done for all_ means that `make` wanted to execute the target `all` from the `Makefile` and that it found there's nothing to do. Please open an new question for that and include the above details, I'm sure we get this resolved.